# Ruby/Rails/HTML - Create New Table Row After X cells from loop

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, for-loop

I'm using Rails to display a set of data. The problem is that data is so large I dont really do the usually for each loop since I creates this insanely long list.

My solution would be to create some form of table where after 10 records create a new cell and after 5 cells create a new row.  I'm not really that comfortable with for loops in rails so I figured throw the question out.

Right now I have...

```
<strong> Person Data Set: </strong><br />
<% for person in @persons %>
   <%= interest.name %> <br />
<% end %>
```

So I can I create a loop similar to this?

```
  <strong> Person Data Set: </strong><br />
  <table>
  <tr>
  *****for each 5 cells???? *****
  <td>
  *****For each 10 records?? ***
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Has anyone had to deal with an issue like this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `each_slice` method. With [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) (I really don't like ERB but the idea is the same):

```
%strong
  Person Data Set:
%br
%table
  - @persons.each_slice(10) do |ten_people| 
    %tr
      - ten_people.each_slice(5) do |five_people|
        %td
          - five_people.each do |person|
            %p= person.name
```