# Rails: load table cells two across at a time

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure out a way to do it. Essentially I want to load (in ERB, from a collection fetched via Rails) an HTML table with cells such that the first row has the first two records, the second row has the next two, etc. Something like this:

```
-----------
| 1  |  2 |
| 3  |  4 |
| 5  |  6 |
-----------
```

Seems like there would be a Ruby/Rails way to iterate over a collection two records at a time.

Comment: Well an easy way to do this would involve using your standard loop to iterate over records and be mindful of when you place your HTML table tags.

Answer (score 8):

Ah, figured it out moments after posting, with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304403/ruby-rails-html-create-new-table-row-after-x-cells-from-loop).

For posterity's sake, here's my solution:

```
  <% @users.each_slice(2) do |two| %>
     <tr>
        <% two.each do |p| %>
           <td>
              <%= p.id %>
           </td>
        <% end %>
     </tr>
  <% end %>
```